# Show availability/busy status across multiple Google calendars

Tags: google-calendar

I'm currently connected to three Google calendars.

- One is my office calendar where I keep track of my work plans when I am focusing on certain projects and whatnot.
- Another is where I keep my meetings with other people
- The third is a shared office calendar where my team tracks our meetings.

What I would like to do is give out my busy/available info. The only way I can do at is by making all three calendars public and someone would have to watch all three to be able to follow my availability.

Is there some way to give other people in my company the ability to subscribe to my true available/busy schedule with a single feed?

Answer (score 15):

So you can grab the embed code from the html link in the share settings and splice them together manually. I needed this and just now experimented and it works.
There are four parts to a public calendar link.

So they are all like this

1. "https://google.com/calendar/"
2. embed type + "?"
3. "src=" + unique string/name
4. "&ctz=" + timezone string (optional)

And it turns out you can add "&src=UNIQUESTRING" an often as you like.
So making sure that either your calendars are wide open, showing free/busy or you are sharing with someone who has been given permission to the calendar in your share settings.

The title for the page is pulled from the first calendar in your src string. And all the colors are the same so you can't tell which calendar is which.

### Embed

determines the embed type.

**htmlembed**
[image]
**embed**
[image]
**src=**
a unique string like this one for NCAA UK basketball schedule

```
src=ncaab_292_%254bentucky%2B%2557ildcats%23sports%40group.v.calendar.google.com
```

**&ctz=**
I assume it is for current time zone. Sets your timezone offset

```
&ctz=America/New_York
```

So here is a link to a combination of UofK basketball,Jewish Holidays, a home maintenance calendar and a local hackerspace in my hometown.

https://www.google.com/calendar/htmlembed?src=1n5qvjga6i4t6lde35vq5dg8ds%40group.calendar.google.com&src=9fjf6vkf1ou50j2umnju2lnrss%40group.calendar.google.com&src=en.jewish%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com&src=ncaab_292_%254bentucky%2B%2557ildcats%23sports%40group.v.calendar.google.com&ctz=America/New_York

Comment: turns out that whenever you have more than 1 it forces you to htmlembed. Also you can add a title by starting it with ?title=Title%20Here&src=...

Comment: I just found this from last year and thought "whoa"! This is  a thorough and complete answer. Probably my best answer ever. I tried to upvote this and it wouldn't let me b/c "You can't vote for your own post". That's dumb. I really like this "your own post".

Comment: This is great! The only issue is if you don't want other people to see the names of the calendars you're sharing, but I haven't found a solution for that yet.

Comment: FYI: Adding `noCache` as a URL param seems to keep  google from caching shared calendars.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to combine calendars to show people, but it is currently not possible to just combine the available/busy information.

[This blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20111014223037/http://murphymac.com/share-busy-free-info-for-multiple-google-calendars/) explains how to create a link to a calendar with your combined availability information, but it doesn't quite accomplish what you need.

Comment: the link is dead.

Comment: Here is a link to a working archive.org snapshot of the page: https://web.archive.org/web/20111014223037/http://murphymac.com/share-busy-free-info-for-multiple-google-calendars/

Comment: thanks, updated the link in the answer