# Publish free/busy status of multiple Exchange365 calendars

Tags: calendar, office-365

I have multiple calendars in Office 365 and would like to publish on the web my free/available status with respect to *all* the calendar. The same question have been asked for Google Calendar here: [Show availability/busy status across multiple Google calendars](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/8672/show-availability-busy-status-across-multiple-google-calendars), but the answer does not apply to my problem, as the URL generated by Office 365 is “opaque.”